# Can anyone translate this into python?

Tags: c, python-3.x, function, math

```
dow(m,d,y) {
    y-=m<3;
    return(y+y/4-y/100+y/400+"-bed=pen+mad."[m]+d)%7;
}
```

The function's purpose is to find what day(Su-Sa) will the provided date(1-31) land on in any given month and year.

I'm not sure how this function works because it was written in C. Mostly I don't know what
the `y-=m<3` is for, or what the `"-bed=pen+mad."` does (is this just a string?).
here is my source: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/node73.html

Comment: use datetime module .... dont translate cryptic c. `y-=m<3` removes 1 from `y` if the month is 0,1 or 2 - part 1 or the return looks like leap year calculations

Comment: This wouldn't work as I'm using it for a calendar. I need a function that tells me what day the first is going to be so it can generate the correct calendar template.

Comment: `"-bed=pen+mad."` is a string literal. Its value is an address, which might be anywhere.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's got an index operator right after it, so it's pulling out some character or other and using that character's ASCII value as an adjustment.  Way too damn clever, but not nonsense.

Comment: In C, getting the index in a string returns the character code. The translation of the string "-bed=pen+mad." in character codes is the array, [45,98,101,100,61,112,101,110,43,109,97,100,46]. TBH, I have no idea what part this plays x-)

Comment: @Codesmith The entire thing is inside `( ... ) % 7`, so only the residues modulo 7 matter: `[3, 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2]`.  In context, this has to be the offset from Monday to apply for each month.  I'm not curious enough to actually validate that, though.  And it's not clear to me whether the function takes 1- or 0-based month and day numbers.

Comment: The actual array is `{ 0, 0, 31, 31+27, 31+27+31, 31+27+31+30 ...` which counts days from the beginning of the year to the beginning of each month. The first entry in the obfuscated array (`'-'` or `45`) is not used since the months are numbered 1 through 12. The rest of the entries only need to be correct modulo 7, due to the `%7` at the end of the expression. So the person who wrote the code had lots of flexibility in choosing letters that where correct mod 7.

Comment: `y -= m<3` means the same thing in C as it does in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the python datetime module:

```
import datetime
dayOfWeek = datetime.datetime(y, m, d).weekday()
```

`dayOfWeek` will then be an integer between 0 and 6 corresponding to Monday - Sunday.

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#date-objects) for more details.